# fxmlLoader.load() will not load object hiearchy

Tags: javafx, controller, fxmlloader

I have 2 windows (login and main) with appropriate controllers.

I got this piece of code. This is located in LoginController.java. When I run app, it will open login window from /fxml/login.fxml where the LoginController is set with fx:controller. Then there is Sign In button. Method signIn() is asociated with this button. When i click it, it will close Login window, get controller of main window and open main window from specific fxml file (/fxml/main.fxml). Meanwhile it will get strings from Login window's text fields and pass them to the MainController (those credentials are used in execution of SQL statements).

```
public void signIn(ActionEvent event) {
    MngApi.closeWindow(btn); //closes parent window of specified node

    try{            
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/main.fxml"));            
        Parent root1 = fxmlLoader.load();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("PrintED");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root1, 1058, 763));//1058, 763
        MainController ctrl = fxmlLoader.getController();
        ctrl.setCredentials(uName.getText(), uPasswd.getText(), 
        ipAddress.getText(), dbName.getText());            
        stage.show();


    }catch (IOException e){

    }

}//signIn end
```

Now this is the problem: When i click Sign In button, the signIn() method will execute, Login window will close and SUCCESSFUL BUILD will pop up. No other window will open. After debugging I found out that program will stop at this line (everything before is done)

```
Parent root1 = fxmlLoader.load();
```

No error, no information, only successfull build. The most mysterious thing for me is that it worked before! Login wondow got closed and main windows appeared. I only added some new methods, action events and stuff. I made no changes to LoginController and fxml file. I only made changes to MainController (added methods and action event for buttons in main.fxml).

I have no idea what's bad and i am clueless. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found out whats wrong. The error was in initilize() method. There i put a method which should initialize columns in my TreeTableView. I thought that when i run program, initialize wil execute (after Controller constructor) and it will run code line by line. so i put there initializeColumns() method, si it will execute first and only once. Looked like this:

```
public void initialize(){
    initializeOrdersColumns();

    //this listener will load (refresh) orders automaticaly when Orders Tab is selected
    tabOrders.setOnSelectionChanged((event) -> {
        if (tabOrders.isSelected()) {

            List<TreeItem<Order>> allOrdersList = new ArrayList<>();
            stackItems(allOrdersList, root);

        root = new TreeItem<>();
        ttwOrders.setRoot(root);
        ttwOrders.setShowRoot(false);

        }                     
    });

    //When we click refresh button, orders tab will reload Orders
    btnOrdersRefresh.setOnAction((event) -> {

        List<TreeItem<Order>> allOrdersList = new ArrayList<>();
        stackItems(allOrdersList, root);

        root = new TreeItem<>();
        ttwOrders.setRoot(root);
        ttwOrders.setShowRoot(false);

    });

}//end of initialize()
```

After I deleted content of initialize() method, everything went well, so it was obvious that error code is in there. Then I commented all code except first method (initializeColumns()) and program went wrong. When I commented only initializeColumns() method the program went well again. So it was clear, initializeColumns() cannot be in initialize() method. Don't know why yet, but i will find out.